# Python itertools function: inconsistent output

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have been pondering on why the output of these scripts is inconsisten. Could anyone help me on this?

```
import itertools
from itertools import tee
from itertools import islice

words = ['Salad','with','Chocolate','and','potatoes']
nwise = lambda xs,n=2: zip(*(islice(xs,idx,None) for idx,xs in enumerate(tee(xs,n))))
doubles = list(map(lambda x: " ".join(x), nwise(words,2)))
triples = list(map(lambda x: " ".join(x), nwise(words,3)))
quadrouples = list(map(lambda x: " ".join(x), nwise(words,4)))
words.extend(doubles)
words.extend(triples)
words.extend(quadrouples)
print(words)
```

The result of this is `['Salad', 'with', 'Chocolate', 'and', 'potatoes', 'Salad with', 'with Chocolate', 'Chocolate and', 'and potatoes', 'Salad with Chocolate', 'with Chocolate and', 'Chocolate and potatoes', 'Salad with Chocolate and', 'with Chocolate and potatoes']`

```
import itertools
from itertools import tee
from itertools import islice

words = ['Salad','with','Chocolate','and','potatoes']
nwise = lambda xs,n=2: zip(*(islice(xs,idx,None) for idx,xs in enumerate(tee(xs,n))))
for i in range(2,5):
    new = list(map(lambda x: " ".join(x), nwise(words,i)))
    words.extend(new)
print(words)
```

The result of this is `['Salad', 'with', 'Chocolate', 'and', 'potatoes', 'Salad with', 'with Chocolate', 'Chocolate and', 'and potatoes', 'Salad with Chocolate', 'with Chocolate and', 'Chocolate and potatoes', 'and potatoes Salad with', 'potatoes Salad with with Chocolate', 'Salad with with Chocolate Chocolate and', 'with Chocolate Chocolate and and potatoes', 'Salad with Chocolate and', 'with Chocolate and potatoes', 'Chocolate and potatoes Salad with', 'and potatoes Salad with with Chocolate', 'potatoes Salad with with Chocolate Chocolate and', 'Salad with with Chocolate Chocolate and and potatoes', 'with Chocolate Chocolate and and potatoes Salad with Chocolate', 'Chocolate and and potatoes Salad with Chocolate with Chocolate and', 'and potatoes Salad with Chocolate with Chocolate and Chocolate and potatoes', 'Salad with Chocolate with Chocolate and Chocolate and potatoes and potatoes Salad with', 'with Chocolate and Chocolate and potatoes and potatoes Salad with potatoes Salad with with Chocolate', 'Chocolate and potatoes and potatoes Salad with potatoes Salad with with Chocolate Salad with with Chocolate Chocolate and', 'and potatoes Salad with potatoes Salad with with Chocolate Salad with with Chocolate Chocolate and with Chocolate Chocolate and and potatoes']`

Why does the for loop with the range() function produce inconsistent results to the line-by-line approach?

Comment: You're appending to `words` on every iteration, thus adding more words to the list to pass to `nwise`.

Comment: Because the `i` is **not bounded** in the **lambda expression**.

Comment: You don't need a lambda expression in the calls to `map`; `lambda x : " ".join(x)` behaves the same as `" ".join`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: That's not a problem here; the `map` is run to completion before `i` changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally safer to [create a new collection](https://bugs.python.org/issue30826#msg302874) when looping to modify it.

Extend to a new list, e.g. `words_`:

```
...
words_ = []
for i in range(2, 5):
    new = list(map(lambda x: " ".join(x), nwise(words,i)))
    words_.extend(new)
print(words_)
```

---

Alternatively, extend the existing `words` list with a `new` list of desired results.

Replace:

```
...
for i in range(2,5):
    new = list(map(lambda x: " ".join(x), nwise(words,i)))
    words.extend(new)
...
```

with

```
... 
new = [" ".join(x) for i in range(2, 5) for x in nwise(words,i)]
words.extend(new)
...
```

Comment: While it's the cause of the logic error, the mutation and iteration are not intermingled as in the normal case where you iterate an object while mutating it within the loop (which can cause infinite or foreshortened loops). This iteration is over a range, while the mutation applies to `words` (which is an input/output on each loop, but not the value the loop iterates directly). Your solution is fine (defer changes to `words` until after all `nwise` work is done), but the explanation is off; there would be nothing unpythonic about this code if the *intent* was to build on the previous outputs.

Comment: Yes I see how the wording can be misinterpreted.  I will edit.  Thanks.